# La conexión no se cerró. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error?, alguien que me oriente, ya que me marca que no se a cerrado la conexión y por ende se queda esperando y no carga la página, en la parte de abajo dejo mi `clsConexion`, esto lo conecto por medio de una `IP`, les comento que por precaución no pongo datos de `IP` y contraseña, dejo mi Clase donde hago el proceso de `CRUD`, les comento que en el `WebConfig` no establecer alguna conexión con la `BD` ya que tiene una clase para ello, aun así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], si la pongo pasa lo mismo que comento.

---

ya coloque el código siguiente, pero me sigue saliendo el mismos error aparte anexo otro error cuando intento llamar la pagina, esto no pasaba anteriormente:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Alumno", "Alumno", "View", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
 public List<Alumno> findAll()
    {
        List<Alumno> LisAlumno = new List<Alumno>();

        string findAll = "select * from Persona";
        try
        {

            conn = new SqlCommand(findAll, objConexion.getcon());
            objConexion.getcon().Open();
            SqlDataReader read = conn.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {

                Alumno objAlumno = new Alumno();
                objAlumno.IdAlumno = Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
                objAlumno.Nombre = read[1].ToString();
                objAlumno.Apellido1 = read[2].ToString();
                objAlumno.Telefono1 = read[3].ToString();
                LisAlumno.Add(objAlumno);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            objConexion.getcon().Close();
            objConexion.cerrarConexion();
        }
        return LisAlumno;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mdel.neg
{
    public class Conexion
    {
        public static Conexion objConexion = null;
        private SqlConnection conn;

        private Conexion()
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source= **anonimo**;Initial Catalog=CndComprobaciones2013Users;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usuIndicador;Password=**anonimo**;Connection Timeout = 36000");
        }

        public static Conexion SaberEstado()
        {
            if (objConexion == null)
            {
                objConexion = new Conexion();
            }
            return objConexion;
        }
        public SqlConnection getcon()
        {
            return conn;
        }
        public void cerrarConexion()
        {
            objConexion = null;

        }

    }
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using model.entity;



namespace mdel.neg
{
    public class AlumnoDao:obligatorio<Alumno>
    {
        private Conexion objConexion;

        private SqlCommand comando;

        public AlumnoDao()
        {
            objConexion = Conexion.SaberEstado();
        }

        public void crear(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            string crear = "insert into Persona(idAlumno,nombre,Apellido,Telefono)values('" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'+'" + objAlumno.Nombre + "'+'" + objAlumno.Apellido1 + "''" + objAlumno.Telefono1 + "')";
            try
            {
                comando = new SqlCommand(crear, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();

            }
        }
        public void Actualizar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            string actualizar = "update Persona set nombre='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "',Apellido='" + objAlumno.Apellido1 + "',Telefono='" + objAlumno.Telefono1 + "' Where idAlumno ='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";
            try
            {
                comando = new SqlCommand(actualizar, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();
            }
        }
        public void Eliminar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            string eliminar = "'delete from Persona where idAlumno ='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";

            try
            {
                comando = new SqlCommand(eliminar, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();
            }
        }
        public bool find(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            bool ExistenRegistros;
            string find = "select * from Persona where idAlumno = '" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";
            try
            {
                comando = new SqlCommand(find, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                SqlDataReader read = comando.ExecuteReader();
                ExistenRegistros = read.Read();
                if (ExistenRegistros)
                {
                    objAlumno.IdAlumno = Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
                    objAlumno.Nombre = read[1].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Apellido1 = read[2].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Telefono1 = read[3].ToString();

                    objAlumno.Estado = 99;

                }
                else
                {
                    objAlumno.Estado = 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return ExistenRegistros;

        }
        public List<Alumno> findAll()
        {
            List<Alumno> LisAlumno = new List<Alumno>();

            string findAll = "select * from Persona";
            try
            {
                comando = new SqlCommand(findAll, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                SqlDataReader read = comando.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    Alumno objAlumno = new Alumno();
                    objAlumno.IdAlumno = Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
                    objAlumno.Nombre = read[1].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Apellido1 = read[2].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Telefono1 = read[3].ToString();
                    LisAlumno.Add(objAlumno);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return LisAlumno;
        }


        public void actualzar(Alumno obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void eliminar(Alumno obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public List<Alumno> finAll()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: no ubico en donde esta el error. esta en el metodo de  ´public List<Alumno> findAll()´  ?

Comment: En algún método no cierras la conexión, y por ello lo estas volviendo abrir, en el metodo de Alumno findAll() -> objConexion.getcon().Open();

Comment: Alguna solucion que me puedan brindar ya que en el método findAll() trata de cerrar la conexion pero no hubico en que parte lo debo de cerrar :/

Comment: una opcion es que cada vez que habras una conexion verifica el estado. if(conexion.State != ConnectionState.Open) conexion.Close() else conexion.Open();  cada vez que hagas algun uso del los recursos.

Answer (score 0):

En tu metodo  find de Alumno no cierras la conexion

```
finally
{
      objConexion.getcon().Close();
      objConexion.cerrarConexion();
}
```

y cuando pasas a otro metodo lo vuelves abrir (Cuando ya esta abierta).

--

```
public List<Alumno> findAll()
        {
            List<Alumno> LisAlumno = new List<Alumno>();

            string findAll = "select * from Persona";
            try
            {
                comando = new SqlCommand(findAll, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                SqlDataReader read = comando.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    Alumno objAlumno = new Alumno();
                    objAlumno.IdAlumno = Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
                    objAlumno.Nombre = read[1].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Apellido1 = read[2].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Telefono1 = read[3].ToString();
                    LisAlumno.Add(objAlumno);
                }
            }
           finally
         {
        objConexion.getcon().Close();
        objConexion.cerrarConexion();
        }
            return LisAlumno;
        }
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Gracias @JuanL, pero esto ya lo había intentado y no funciona, pero se agradece tu aporte :D

Comment: Actualiza tu codigo, para darte una mejor solucion, si no lo has resuelto

Comment: Juan ya coloque de nuevo lo que me comentas en el código tal cual pero me sale el mismo mensaje, aparte cuando lo mando a llamar me sale otro error.Las siguientes secciones se han definido, pero no se han presentado para la página de diseño "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "featured".

Comment: el error de la bd abierta es en solo ese metodo de listAll() ? o en todos los metodos?

Comment: Solo era en ese metodo ya lo solucione... gracias :D

Comment: tengo un nuevo error. No se encuentra la vista 'Inicio' ni su vista maestra o no hay un motor de búsqueda que admita las ubicaciones de búsqueda. Se buscó en las siguientes ubicaciones:  ~/Views/Alumno/Inicio.aspx
~/Views/Alumno/Inicio.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Inicio.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Inicio.ascx
~/Views/Alumno/Inicio.cshtml
~/Views/Alumno/Inicio.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Inicio.cshtml

Comment: En el controlador donde llamas el methodo contiene la vista?